# Azure Search: exact match of phrase, not term

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

is there a way to find documents, which property **exactly** match term?

E.g.: search for **Test**. Expected result:

```
{
  clientName: "Test"
}
```

and not "Test client", "Test1" or whatever.

Currently I see only $filter possibility, though I'm not sure if it's appropriate (may be slower etc).

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $filter for this purpose; that is its intended usage. It uses the same kind of inverted index as full text searches without the overhead of relevance scoring, so if your query contains only filters it should actually be faster.